# Kendo UI grid column template with nested evaluations - how to?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

Kendo UI v2015.2.805

I have a KendoGrid with a template column that does a conditional to determine if a set of buttons should be added, if so additional evaluations are needed, and I can't figure out how to nest them.

The below works but does not have the required additional evaluation:

```
{ field: "Served", title: "Served", 
template: "<div>" + 
"#= (Kind==0 || Kind==7) ? '" + 
"<button type=\"button\" data-id=\"12345\">Yes</button>" + 
"<button type=\"button\" data-id=\"54321\">No</button>" + 
"' : " +  
"'NO BUTTON HERE'" +  
"#</div>"
```

I multi-lined it to try to get it to look good, which it does not. The idea is that if the Kind = 0 or 7 then show two buttons otherwise do not.  Works great.

However I need to evaluate the data-id to #= ID #, so I try:

```
" <button type=\"button\" data-id=\"' #= ID # '\">Yes</button>"
```

I know I need to 'drop out' of the quoted string to get the evaluation to work and since I have used double quotes for the whole expression I am returning the button in the conditional as a single quoted string, and as such escaping the button attributes, but I can't get it to evaluate the #=.

I've tried so many different combinations I've lost track.

So what is the 'right-way' to do this?

A SOLUTION:

Accepting David's answer with a modification to use template evaluation in the function:

```
{ field: "Served", title: "Served", 
  template: function (data) {
    switch (data.Kind) {
      case 0:
      case 7:
        var template = kendo.template("<button type='button' data-id='#= ID #' >Yes</button><button type='button' data-id='#= ID #'>No</button>");
        return template(data);
      default:
        return '';
    }
}
```

Having the function perform the initial test removes one level and allows 'normal' evaluation to occur.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were using asp.net mvc builders or not, so I proposed a solution that would of been easy to use with mvc builders.

but this is the right aproach if you are client side and control the full initialization :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function instead I Beleive it will would make things so much easier for you.

your template can be `"#= buildButtons(data) #"`

```
function buildButtons(model) {
    if (model.Kind == 0 || model.Kind == 7) {
        return "hello world";
    }

    return "";
}
```

here is a code sample
https://dojo.telerik.com/UQuqAfuv

```
<div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
  var people = [
    { id: 1, firstName: 'David', lastName: 'Lebee' },
    { id: 2, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
  ];

  $('#grid').kendoGrid({ 
        dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function(options) {
            options.success(people);
          }
        }
      },
        columns: [
        { field: 'firstName', title: 'First Name'  },
        { field: 'lastName', title: 'Last Name' },
        { title: 'Actions', template: '#= buildActions(data) #'}
      ]
  });


  function buildActions(model) {
        if (model.firstName == "David") {
        return 'Hello David';
      }

      return '';
  }
  </script>
```